# Add Beyond compare to Explorer's right click

Tags: beyondcompare3

I have been using Beyond Compare 3 in my previous company and it comes in handy every time I need to compare files/folders. Right-clicking on the file would open up BC's option to compare it against another file . I recently installed BC 3 in my new PC. Very strange is that I'm not getting the BC default option on right-clicking of file.

Can someone guide on this?

Comment: Looks like this is the information you're looking for: https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_shellex

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm that the [article](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_shellex) mentioned in the above comments works as expected. I am using a machine with Windows 7 64-bit.

> To enable the shell extension after installation:
>
> - Select **Tools** | **Options** and pick the **Startup** tab.
> - In the Explorer Integration group, enable the **Include Beyond Compare in Explorer context menu** option.
>
> The **Include Beyond Compare in Explorer context menu** check box isn't available if you selected **Create portable install** when you installed Beyond Compare.  To enable it, install Beyond Compare again and select **Install for all users** or **Install for current user**.

---

As a side note, I will mention that this right-click behavior is buggy in Beyond Compare 3. (If you have right-click options, everything is great, but if you do not have any of the right-click options, good luck getting them to show up.) We had BC 3 installed on several machines with Windows 7 32-bit, and myself and several co-workers could not get the `Compare` or `Select Left File for Compare` options to show up in the right-click menu. We contacted support, we installed their patch, nothing worked. Other co-workers with similar machines were *not* affected by the issue for some reason. The issue was never actually resolved; eventually our laptops were replaced, and we have not had the problem since then.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the official Beyond Compare 3.3.13 installer. If you're using a custom installer provided by your company, it's possible it didn't install the shell extension correctly.

To change from a custom installer to an official installer, uninstall it, reboot your computer, then install using the official installer.

Version 3.3.13 download page: http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=dl3_en

Comment: Good point. Come to think of it, we may have had a custom installer for BC 3 at that point in time... although once we starting problem-solving we were pretty keen on keeping installers and patches original.